# Html: how to download the link on-click, rather than right click and save as

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

In my html file i want to have an image link when clicked it start downloading the image to the local folder. Generally to download a link, we have to right click and then select save as.

I tried the following:

```
 var href = document.createElement("a");
 href.setAttribute("href", url1);
 href.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Image Download"));
 href.setAttribute("download", "test.jpg");
 contentDiv.appendChild(href);
```

But its still not working. i click, the image is opened in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Instead try something along the lines of this in your HTML:

```html
<a download="test.jpg" href="insert/path" title="insertName">
insert text here!!
</a>
```

Hopefully this helps, however I've heard this only works in certain browsers!

*Note - I believe you need to do it just like I have it, just replace the place holders!!

Comment: `<a download="test.jpg" href="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7555/29856053076_43cceef1b6_o.jpg">download</a>` i tried this in firefox. it didnt work

Comment: `href="insert/path/(Where you want the user to save it to)" ` what does this mean. My image href is `https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7555/29856053076_43‌​ccee‌​f1b6_o.jpg`

Comment: thank you for the help. i am desperate for some working solution. can you clarify my comment

Comment: I dont need to show a image. text is sufficient: `<a download="test" href="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7555/29856053076_43ccee‌​f1b6_o.jpg">download‌​</a>`  but its not working

Comment: Actually you can just remove the img part all together, which may actually be better. Sorry, if it sounds like I don't know what I'm doing, I'm still learning! p.s. I tested it and there is a problem with the image, the problem is in the image itself, though, not the code

Answer (score 1):

In the [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> This attribute, if present, indicates that the author intends the
>   hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource so that when the user
>   clicks on the link they will be prompted to save it as a local file.
>   If the attribute has a value, the value will be used as the pre-filled
>   file name in the Save prompt that opens when the user clicks on the
>   link (the user can change the name before actually saving the file of
>   course). There are no restrictions on allowed values (though / and \
>   will be converted to underscores, preventing specific path hints), but
>   you should consider that most file systems have limitations with
>   regard to what punctuation is supported in file names, and browsers
>   are likely to adjust file names accordingly.

The `download` attribute is not supported in Firefox.

However, if you're using Chrome, with JavaScript, you could try with something like this:

```js
var imageURL, contentDiv, href, img;
imageURL = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tango-icon-library/48/go-home-128.png";

contentDiv = document.getElementById("contentDiv");

href = document.createElement("a");
href.setAttribute("href", imageURL);
href.setAttribute("download", imageURL);

img = document.createElement("img");
img.alt = "Download image";
img.title = img.alt;
img.src = imageURL;

href.appendChild(img);
contentDiv.appendChild(href);
```

```html
<div id="contentDiv"></div>
```

**Note:**
In Google Chrome, you can use the `download` attribute without setting the url to download.

Example:

```html
<a href="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tango-icon-library/48/go-home-128.png" download>Image Download</a>
```

Comment: The href.setAttribute("download", "download"); is different from your code @SanthoshYedidi

Comment: i am using `href.setAttribute("download", "test.jpg");` how that difference from `href.setAttribute("download", "download")`. only the test.jpg and download, what difference it will make

Comment: Actually, this attribute is not working in Firefox. I've made some changes in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Send the following response headers from server to download a file that otherwise would be displayed in browser itself:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME
Content-Type: application/x-force-download; name="FILENAME"
```

where the `FILENAME` is desired name for the file to have when downloaded.